# How to stop operating system's interrupts for python code that executes a real-time process on both Mac and Win

Tags: python, windows, macos, real-time, interrupt

I have an experimental setup that should run in real-time. It includes several devices that are controlled by a single laptop. Due to operating system's interrupts, some of the devices don't activate simultaneously, but have some random delay in between. We observe some jittering in the impulses sent to the devices as well. From our tests, we concluded that the main cause of these issues is operating system's interrupts.
We have two laptops, one running Windows and one with Mac. If we can find a solution for either, we can restrict ourselves for that specific one.
We are running a Python program (cannot change the programming language).
Note that our "real-time" requirements are not too strict. If we can get the jittering within a 1ms range, it is sufficient (currently we have a jitter of about 50ms).

Setting up affinity of the process in the operating system doesn't seem to help much.
We found about python multiprocessing library, but from what I understand, it cannot prevent the operating system's interference.

I'd like to use this library to specify the cores to run the code on, but I don't know of any way to force the operating system to work only on the remaining cores. If anyone knows of some method to do so, please share it with us.

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to do it for Python, at least, not for CPython, which is using a lot of system calls, and every system call is a context switch.

Python is not suitable for real-time processing at all, not in its current form. Both Mac and Windows are also not suitable for your task. Try Linux - a vanilla kernel is ok, no need for any real-time patches.

Now, if you want to disable the interrupts for some real-time process that is pinned to a CPU core, you can do it:

- Compile your Linux kernel with NOHZ_FULL support.
- Isolate the chosen CPU core (`isolcpus=...` option)
- `nohz_full=... rcu_nocbs=...` where `...` is your list of isolated CPUs
- Then pin your real-time processes to the selected CPU cores. Not any combination of cores can be isolated - you'd need to experiment with your platform.

Next, make sure your real-time process never context-switch. In practice it means:

- Use a real-time scheduling policy, it'll hint the Linux kernel not to touch this process
- Never use any system calls, at all. For communication with the other threads use shared memory and lock-free data structures. If you need to lock - use only spin-locks. Your process must always consume 100% of the CPU.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for you reply. I understand the Python is not suited for real-time processing. The problem is that I need to use a library for my experiment design which runs on python. I was hoping to achieve a latency that is "good enough" for the experiment.
Someone asked about the system specifications for the laptops we use, thus I was planning to go to the lab and get the needed specs, but I can't see that comment anymore. I was hoping that there is some way to use the system that we have.

Comment: As for Linux, thank you very much for the explanation. I actually also recommended my colleagues to switch, but as it stands, it may be relevant only for our next experiment due to time limitations and the fact that no one at our lab is familiar with Linux.

Comment: In the hard real-time setup I described above, you can use a non-realtime language aside the real-time task for lower frequency control. In fact, I'm routinely doing exactly this in the industrial robotic control, with hard real-time task communicating with a Racket runtime in a separate thread, where Racket does complex calculations, use external high latency libraries, etc., but the hard real-time process can take over if the slow process failed to deliver a next step calculation. See the example here: https://github.com/combinatorylogic/racket-embed - you can try to do the same for Python